# Why do you need to not use cement when laying block paving?

Tags: driveway, cement, paving

When you lay block paving surely you have to lay it with cement rather than just sand as it hold the block down securely.

So why is this?

Comment: Doesn't gravity do that? The point of block paving is to tolerate some movement yet act as a solid surface. What would you cement it _to_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A properly prepared sand base for the paving blocks provides a level surface, a support for the expected loads on the pavers and a means of allowing rain and other water run-off. The blocks are held in place by gravity and by properly preparing the perimeter of the paving area, which can be landscape timbers, concrete borders or similar.

There are liquids known as landscape binders that can be applied to the sand, but they are primarily used where slopes are involved, preventing wash-away erosion. I'm not certain if applying binder to the sand would remove the ability for rain and water seep-through, but I suspect that it would.

Concrete does not give the same visual appeal and if used as a grouting material increases the labor involved in building a paved area.

Comment: I agree a well compacted crushed quarry or shale is the best base then leveled with sand . If the sides are solid so the sand and gravel cannot move the pavers can carry quite a load, if they start moving the base was not thick enough or packed enough, the good thing is more can be added and the same pavers reused.+

Comment: The concrete will also crack.